# Display an Value based on if condition in SuiteCRM pdf templates

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

How to display value based on condition in PDF templates in SuiteCRM

```
  {if ! isset($aos_products_quotes_product_discount )}
    <p style="font-style: italic;">Discount</p>
  {/if}
```

$aos_products_quotes_product_discount ,
is an line item module field.i need to print as " Discount " if this field has some .

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you already have the `$aos_products_quotes_product_discount` variable defined,

If you want to print the label if the field has some value, use:

```
{if $aos_products_quotes_product_discount}
  <p style="font-style: italic;">Discount</p>
{/if}
```

If you want to print the value if the value exists, you'd use something like

```
{if $aos_products_quotes_product_discount}
  <p style="font-style: italic;">Discount: {$aos_products_quotes_product_discount}</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: where's the documentation for that syntax?